# Word for "valid excuse"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms, compound-words

I'm searching for a word that would mean an excuse is valid. An *excuse* sounds like something that is negative, but a *valid excuse* it positive/neutral. Is there such a word?

Comment: *valid excuse* is what's called for. And *excuse* is not necessarily negative.

Comment: Why isn't 'valid excuse' acceptable?

Comment: @marcellothearcane it works fine, but I was just curious if there is a single word that fits.

Comment: Perhaps 'reason'.

Comment: @Drew True, but there is a pretty strong negative connotation ('He's always making excuses'). But this is perhaps true for any words meaning 'justify / explain an apparent shortcoming'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ***justification*** is a positively associated ***explanation*** for something.

> **justification** *noun*
>   1.1 Good reason for something that exists or has been done.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/justification)

Comment: If you want more reputation points so that you can comment on people's posts, then you need to write good answers. Perhaps you can take the tour of the site and see what comprises a good answer. Else you might never receive enough reputation points to make comments. Your attempted   here  lacks any links to any reference material, such as a decent dictionary (example: Oxfordl.  The question itself is poor as it fails to indicate any research.

Comment: I've added a dictionary entry for you. Feel free to edit further or to roll back my changes.